# How to get deferred deep-link data on Android with Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, deep-linking, branch.io

I have a Flutter app that works great for both iOS and Android when using a Branch.io QuickLink.  However, we are changing from a Branch.io QuickLink to a Branch.io Journey.

I am using the flutter_branch_sdk package, latest available (3.5.0 as of writing).

With no Flutter code change, the iOS app still works as expected.  However, the Android app is no longer working if the app is NOT installed.

If the app is already installed, then the Android app properly gets the abc=123 information passed in from the Journey.  However, if the app is NOT installed, the abc=123 is not passed in to the app once it's installed via the Journey.

I have verified in Google Play that I have the correct sha256 certificate fingerprint for the 'Enable App Links' in the Android section of Branch.io configuration.

Does anyone have an idea of what I am missing or doing wrong?

I'm not sure what code I could include here that would help.  However if there is something I could include, please let me know.

Thanks for any direction.

Comment: Can you share the Quick Link that is working fine? If not, we'd need to debug this further. You can raise a support ticket here - https://help.branch.io/using-branch/page/submit-a-ticket

Comment: Here is the QuickLink: https://m9186.app.link/smartcredit/?PID=50248